# How to create bullets for toggling between pages/slides

Tags: html, css

I have a page that toggles between divs and the functionality is working, but right now, I only have this:

[image]

I am wanting the black/white containers to be bullets without text in them. Like this:

[image]

```css
#menu li {
 display:block;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #000;
 background:#fff;
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
#menu li.active{
 background:#666;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
 color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
 color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
 padding: 9px 18px;
 display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
 color: #fff;
}
#menu{
 position:fixed;
 top:18%;
 right:1%;
 height: 40px;
 z-index: 70;
 width: 10%;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
 <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
 <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
 <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
 <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add in the description what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: I have no idea even what to do. I'd be happy with a link or something. I tried searching and cannot find anything.

Comment: Hey did you try my answer?

Comment: Did you try my answer? Please follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using multiple `box-shadow` and `border-radius` set to 50%.

Also, you can use another active class to give a different look to the selected bullet. In this case I am using `opacity` to differentiate between an active and an inactive bullet:

```css
.dots {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px green,
              0px 0px 0px 5px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px green,
              0px 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.dots + .dots-active {
  opacity: 1.0
}
```

```html
<div class="dots">
</div>

<div class="dots dots-active">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I just now saw this. Thanks, this gave me the right idea.